# com.google.android.exoplayer2.text.SubtitleDecoderException

Tags: android, android-videoview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-video-player

I'm creating subtitles by simply writing a text file and saving it with `.srt` extension. And all subtitle files which i have created is working fine. (I just checked it with MxPlayer)

Now I'm building a video player which needs to display the subtitles which I have created.

Initially I tried to load subtitles from web just to prepare the code base. And it worked

```
val uri = Uri.parse("https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/subtitles_en.vtt")
val subtitleFormat: Format = Format.createTextSampleFormat(
            null,  // An identifier for the track. May be null.
            MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT,  // The mime type. Must be set correctly.
            Format.NO_VALUE,  // Selection flags for the track.
            "en"
        )
var mediaDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, null))
var subtitleSource = SingleSampleMediaSource(uri, mediaDataSourceFactory,
            subtitleFormat,
            C.TIME_UNSET)
...
...

var videoSource: MediaSource = buildMediaSource(video_uri!!)
var mediaSource: MediaSource =  MergingMediaSource(videoSource, subtitleSource)
```

Now all I have to do is load subtitle file from the local folder  which is located at

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.appname/files/Subtitle/shortmovie.2020.720p.x264.mp4.en.srt
```

I know web file is different and local file is different. But don't know whether it is causing problem or not*

To load I'm following below snippet

```
fun getSubtitleFilePath(context: Context, subtitleFileName: String?): File {
        val path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
        return File(path, "$appFolderName/${subtitleFileName}.srt")
}

val subtitleFilePath = getSubtitleFilePath(this, "shortmovie.2020.720p.x264.mp4.en")
val uri = Uri.parse(subtitleFilePath.toURI().toString())
```

That's all, I just replaced `uri` with local subtitle file.

**Main Problem**

when I try load the subtitles the player is not playing the video. And I'm getting an error

```
Playback error.
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.text.SubtitleDecoderException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: Expected WEBVTT. Got 1

Caused by:
com.google.android.exoplayer2.text.SubtitleDecoderException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException: Expected WEBVTT. Got 1
```

I have no idea what this error about. I just went through [Github issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6885) and found no solution for this.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, no one answered my question I found answer myself.

- first thing is `.vtt` and `.srt` are slightly different.
  in `.vtt` the first line is a text `WEBVTT` [check this](https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/subtitles_en.vtt)
  in `.srt` there is no such thing
- secondly, very important thing is `MimeTypes` in `subtitleFormat`
  it should be `MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP` for `.srt` and `MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT` for `.vtt`
- If you rename `.srt` to `.vtt` and added that first line `WEBVTT` manually some parsing exception will come. So, better check webvtt file whether it is proper or not.

That's all now things are working fine.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my mime type to MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP for local art file. Its working